# Free & overall time

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design, ux-field, ux-designer

There is some over-the-phone consulting service with pay-as-you-go terms of payment and five first minutes for free.  How it can be displayed on App screen during  the call and in the  bill?

Should you display the timer from the very beginning  or after first five minutes...or you should display two timers - an overall and for a free time?  And  how it can be depicted in the bill in compact and easy to understand way (when it displayed on mobile screen)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We did something similar for a taxi firm, this is the solution we came up with, I hope it gives you some ideas, the end platform was a Samsung phone, so it should fit your needs.

[image: Free waiting time]

Sadly this is pre-design, the colour of the timer changes once the billing starts proper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show only one timer, or you'll confuse the user. The most common way is to show the total time elapsed, and after some X amount of free time, the timer changes in a clear way for teh user, usually changing color and adding some message to explain what has happened and how the conditions have changed.

Another common way is to include the $ amount as well. For example, if the clock is under 5 minutes:

```
Time Elapsed: 00:04:50          Amount: $0
```

Then after teh 5 minutes:

```
Time Elapsed: 01:01:01          Amount: $123
```

Finally, you can use a reverse timer. For example, using a countdown from `-05'00''` to `-00'01''` and then change color and go from `+0'00''` to `+n'nn''`

Keep in mind these are just 3 common (and proven) choices, but you should test them out, as in anything UX

Comment: Of course - seemingly random resets of a counter are wayyy better than just telling the user what is going on. When i look at this after 6 minutes i will see a counter which displays a minute which is more confusing than the other alternatives stated here